How to use entry.bind("<FocusIn>", self.method_calling) for Entries made with grid/list
On this link is this code example that generates an entry grid in a Class with get(self) and set(set) method:
from tkinter import *


class Table:

    def __init__(self, root, values):

        total_rows = len(values)
        total_columns = len(values[0])

        # create a 2-D list to store the entry widgets
        self.entries = [[None]*total_columns for _ in range(total_rows)]

        # code for creating table
        for i in range(total_rows):
            for j in range(total_columns):
                e = Entry(root, width=10, fg='blue', font=('Arial',16,'bold'))
                e.grid(row=i, column=j)
                e.insert(END, values[i][j])
                self.entries[i][j] = e  # store entry into list

    # function to get value of entry at (row, col)
    def get(self, row, col):
        try:
            return self.entries[row][col].get()
        except IndexError as ex:
            print("Error on Table.get():", ex)

    # function to set value of entry at (row, col)
    def set(self, row, col, value):
        try:
            self.entries[row][col].delete(0, "end")
            self.entries[row][col].insert("end", value)
        except IndexError as ex:
            print("Error on Table.set():", ex)


# take the data
lst = [(1,'Raj','Mumbai',19),
       (2,'Aaryan','Pune',18),
       (3,'Vaishnavi','Mumbai',20),
       (4,'Rachna','Mumbai',21),
       (5,'Shubham','Delhi',21)]

# create root window
root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")

t = Table(root, lst) # pass lst to Table()

# update entry at row 0 column 1
t.set(0, 1, "hello")

root.mainloop()

Usually, for Entry placed "manually" I can use:
self.entry_path = Entry(root, width=72, font= ('Helvetica 13'))
self.entry_path.insert(INSERT, "Text Entry")
self.entry_path.bind("<FocusIn>", self.method_calling)

to call an event method to get:
def method_calling(self, event):
    self.entry_path.delete(0, END)
    self.entry_path.config(state= "disabled")

but I have no idea how I can .bind or .config Entry from a gird/list.
EDIT:
If I am using like this:
class Table:

    def __init__(self, root, values):

        total_rows = len(values)
        total_columns = len(values[0])

        # create a 2-D list to store the entry widgets
        self.entries = [[None]*total_columns for _ in range(total_rows)]

        # code for creating table
        for i in range(total_rows):
            for j in range(total_columns):
                e = Entry(root, width=10, fg='blue', font=('Arial',16,'bold'))
                e.grid(row=i, column=j)
                e.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda: self.method_calling(i,j))
                e.insert(END, values[i][j])
                self.entries[i][j] = e  # store entry into list

    # function to get value of entry at (row, col)
    def get(self, row, col):
        try:
            return self.entries[row][col].get()
        except IndexError as ex:
            print("Error on Table.get():", ex)

    # function to set value of entry at (row, col)
    def set(self, row, col, value):
        try:
            self.entries[row][col].delete(0, "end")
            self.entries[row][col].insert("end", value)
        except IndexError as ex:
            print("Error on Table.set():", ex)

    def method_calling(self,event,i,j):
        print("row_"+str(i)+" column_"+str(j))


# take the data
lst = [(1,'Raj','Mumbai',19),
       (2,'Aaryan','Pune',18),
       (3,'Vaishnavi','Mumbai',20),
       (4,'Rachna','Mumbai',21),
       (5,'Shubham','Delhi',21)]

# create root window
root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")

t = Table(root, lst) # pass lst to Table()

# update entry at row 0 column 1
t.set(0, 1, "hello")

root.mainloop()

it gives me this error when I click on a cell:

and if I am using the code without "lambda:: in the command and without "event" in the calling methodl like this:
                e.grid(row=i, column=j)
                e.bind("<FocusIn>", self.method_calling(i,j))

....
....
    def method_calling(self,i,j):
        print("row_"+str(i)+" column_"+str(j))

it automatically triggers without pressing anything.


You can call bind at the time that you create the Entry widgets. Have you tried that? e.bind("<FocusIn>", self.method_calling).

As Bryan said, you can create the binding after creating the entry widget and use event.widget to refer the widget of binding inside the callback.

Can you please check my edit?

You need to use default values of arguments to get the required row and column as below:
e.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda evt, i=i, j=j: self.method_calling(i, j))

And the definition of method_calling() should be:
def method_calling(self, i, j):
    print(f"row_{i} column_{j}")


You guys are life savers! Thank you from all my hearth <3
